# Issue upgrading from osx Yosemite to El capitan 10.11.4 on iMac

Tags: macos, mac, osx-yosemite, osx-el-capitan

I'm currently using version 10.11.5 of OS X Yosemite and I tried to upgrade to El Capitan (current version 10.11.4) because I need to upgrade some apps.

The App Store update didn’t work (it continously said “paused” on the download link) so I downloaded it from the Apple website. When I opened the package it said that I needed El Capitan 10.11 but I have no idea how to install that (it said the same thing after I downloaded El Capitan 10.11.1) because I can’t find anything other than the latest versions on the website. How can I pass over to El Capitan?

Answer (score 1):

You downloaded the incorrect package

Apple only have updates if you want to go from 10.11.0 to anything above that (and same for 10.10.0 -10.10.5). If you want to go to El Capitan you have to get it from the app store.

*El Capitan is a major update and can not be downloaded from Apple Website only small updates like 10.10.2 - 10.10.4* Basically if you want to update the digit furthest to the right you can do it on app store or Apple website. Update from the middle can only be done in app store or a non recommended method above.

---

Another option which I **don't recommend**, is to get it from a third party website. A website which I recommend is GetIntoPC. Once you download and install it, you won't be in the latest El Capitan version but just use the file you got from Apple website to update.

Comment: hey first of all: thank you for answering. I've tried following your suggestions but after downloading the package it says that the app "Install OS X El Capitan" can't be used by this disk. Any idea why? It looks like axactly what I need, but i can't manage to install it.

Comment: @Jules follow the instructions further down in the link (at end of this comment) to create a bootable media. https://www.macissues.com/2015/10/01/how-to-overcome-os-x-10-11-el-capitan-not-installing/

Comment: So, I'vre tried but it still doesn't work. Are you sure it is a safe download? Anyway I checked on the apple website once again and i noticed that when talking about upgrading to OS X El Capitan, the website ( http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/ ) showed a caption of the window that pops up when you click on the apple logo on the upper left side and then click on "about this mac". I have that exact same version of Yosemite and the iMac is year 2010. Is it possible that the problem is with the App store? The link is the one I'm talking about and the caption is the second one it shows.